# pysftp download fails because of client exceeded server's internal buffers

Tags: python, pysftp

I need just to download a file from a python script, so the code is simple:

```
import pysftp
sftp = pysftp.Connection('test_host','test',password='test')
sftp.get('testfile', 'c:\\tmp\\testfile3')
```

The download will start and proceed for a few seconds at normal speed and then stall. Nothing more is downloaded and after a few minutes the connection is closed by the server.
The Admin of the server I am connecting to won't disclose any details of the server for 'security reasons', but wrote me that on his end, he can see an error like this:

> SFTP error sending, too many simultaneous client requests.  Client has exceeded the server's internal buffers.

Is there anything I can do about it from the python code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This one is another manifestation of the MAX_REQUEST_SIZE problem described in a post here: [Paramiko Fails to download large files >1GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12486623/paramiko-fails-to-download-large-files-1gb?rq=1)

So I too changed in **sftp_file.py** :

```
MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 32768
```

to

```
MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 1024
```

and magically, the problem seems to be solved.