# Paramiko: Can lowering the MAX_REQUEST_SIZE have significant performance impact?

Tags: python, sftp, paramiko

In paramiko's **sftp_file.py**

```
# Some sftp servers will choke if you send read/write requests larger than
# this size.
MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = 32768
```

I had to lower that constant to '1024' for my SFTP transfers to work:
[pysftp download fails because of client exceeded server's internal buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29628133/pysftp-download-fails-because-of-client-exceeded-servers-internal-buffers/29629223#29629223)

**It seems to me from my testing that SFTP transfer speed was negatively impacted by this - I compared with other clients.**

Can anyone give some more specific reason why this is the case (if it's really true)?

Answer (score 2):

The constant tells how many bytes to read/write in a single request.

The lower the value is, more requests have to be used to transfer a file.

Time you have to wait for a response to a request does NOT grow proportionally with the request size. Unless connecting to a very slow local server, with such a small requests sizes, a connection latency is more important than a connection speed. So overall, the more requests you have to use, the longer it takes to transfer the file.

---

A request size limit can be compensated by dispatching multiple requests in a sequence, without waiting for a response to the previous requests. An SFTP allows that and most SFTP clients do that. Paramiko is one of the few that do not.

Comment: _"An SFTP allows that and most SFTP clients do that. Paramiko is one of the few that do not."_



Don't you know what are the other clients 'that do not'? Just to avoid them for the time being?

Comment: Actually I'm not aware of any. But some will do, as it's the most simple way to implement an SFTP protocol.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this

paramiko.SFTPFile.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE = pow(2, 40)

this worked for me... try lowering the power 40 to 22 if this does not work..

I had trouble prior to this, but now works well

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).