# Paramiko Buffer issue

Tags: python, csv, paramiko

I have a problem of buffer using paramiko, I found the same question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12486623/2662302) and one of the solutions states that:

> Rather than using .get(), if you just call .open() to get an SFTPFile
>   instance, then call .read() on that object, or just hand it to the
>   Python standard library function shutil.copyfileobj() to download the
>   contents. That should avoid the Paramiko prefetch cache, and allow you
>   to download the file even if it's not quite as fast.

Now if I have:

```
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host,username=user,password=pwd)
sftp=ssh.open_sftp()
sftp_file=sftp.open(remote_file_adress)
```

How I save this file-like-object in a csv in my local pc? (the original file is a csv also)

Comment: Probably something like this http://www.programcreek.com/python/example/618/shutil.copyfileobj, `copyfileobj(sftp_file, open('save.csv', 'wb'), 1024)`

Comment: I'm confused about your naming conventions...  `server_address` holds the name of the remote file? Then `shutil.copyfileobj(sftp_file, open('localfile', 'wb'))` should do it. You may find better performance by specifiying a larger block size (e.g., `blocksize=1048576` then `shutil.copyfileobj(sftp_file, open('localfile', 'wb', blocksize), blocksize)`

Comment: @tdelaney thanks, yes I corrected that to be more clear.

Comment: @tdelaney any particular reason for the method taking too long?

Comment: Does it take long? I've worked out an example on my machine with a small file and will update it for a large one. BTW, I also realized there is a bufsize param for the sftp open call also. It may make a difference. I'll post my example then rerun it with a larger file. Then we can have common code to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example that fetches copies a test file on your local machine. The file is much smaller than 1 GIG but gives the general plan.

```
import paramiko
import os
import shutil
import time
import getpass

# get params
user = getpass.getuser()
pwd = getpass.getpass("Enter password: ")
bufsize = 2**20
host = 'localhost'
test_file_lines = 1000000

# create test file
now = time.asctime()
testfile_path = os.path.abspath('deleteme')
local_path = 'deleteme.copy'

print('writing test file...')
start = time.time()
with open(testfile_path, 'w') as fp:
    for _ in range(test_file_lines):
        fp.write(now + '\n')
delta = time.time() - start
file_size = os.stat(testfile_path).st_size
print("file size %d, %d KB/Sec" % (file_size, file_size/1024/delta))

# make connection
ssh=paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host,username=user,password=pwd)
sftp=ssh.open_sftp()
sftp_file=sftp.open(testfile_path, bufsize=bufsize)
print('copying file...')
start = time.time()
shutil.copyfileobj(sftp_file, 
    open(local_path, 'wb', bufsize),
    bufsize)
delta = time.time() - start
print('%.3f seconds, %d KB/Sec' % (delta, file_size/1024/delta))

#assert open(testfile_path).read() == open(local_path).read(), "files match"
```

Running on my machine I got

```
Enter password: 
writing test file...
file size 25000000, 21017 KB/Sec
copying file...
10.225 seconds, 2387 KB/Sec
```

We expect some slow down because there is a read and a write plus network costs (its to local host so doesn't really touch the wire), but that does seem kinda slow. I am using a low-powered laptop with 2 cores and between this app and sshd, used much of the cpu, presumably to do the encryption. A higher powered machine may work better.

Comment: I tried with my credentials your code, works like a charm! thanks a lot